Did southern slavery undercut poor whites?
In the late Roman Republic, slaves priced out Roman citizens. Costly freemen farmers were unable to compete with far lower-cost labour. However, I haven't seen anything written similarly about the Antebellum south.
Given that slavery had become an increasingly integral part of the southern agrarian economy over the last century, surely free farmers who did not own slaves would be increasingly priced out of the labour market as in previous slave economies.
If this did happen, what primary or secondary sources talk about this?

The subject matter certainly is distasteful but I have often wondered what exactly motivated poorer Southern citizens to get killed at scale in order to defend the privileges of the much smaller number of people who benefited from owning slaves.  The economic aspects could be expected to be a factor.

You're right, it is interesting. Colin Woodward's 'Marching Masters' shows that many confederate soldiers were strongly motivated by racist sentiment at the time. Imo, racist 'false consciousness' made them defend an institution which was almost certainly against their economic interests. The interesting thing is that some did reject fighting for the CSA for that reason. During Louisiana's secession convention, the delegate from Winn, Louisiana voted to remain in the union, stating: 'Who wants to fight to keep the Negroes for the wealthy planters?'

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)

IIRC, the argument that something along these lines was going on was actually part of the Republican platform in 1860, and that of the "Free Soil" party before then.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The answer usually lies in the mixture of propaganda and misplaced feelings of belonging. Despite the clear reason for the war, many still clung to the idea of "northern aggression". And as OP mentioned, two scoops of racism.

Link "So, according to the Census of 1860, 30.8 percent of the free families in the confederacy owned slaves. That means that [nearly] every third white person in those states had a direct commitment to slavery."

@PieterGeerkens - Hmmmm. I don't think the contrapositive statement is true (likely a lot of the rest worked as slave drivers, or otherwise worked a career supported by the enslavement of humans), but still <1/3 does not seem an impressively high number to me. (To be fair, TFA was countering misinformation that it was as low as 1%!)

I wonder if the issue wouldn't have manifested itself as the Dutch Disease instead where cotton crowded out other economic activity without necessarily having the direct effect asked about here.  We know cotton was fabulously lucrative for the South and that profit margin itself was driven by slavery.

While only a minority of the Southern White population actually owned slaves, there were many more who aspired to own slaves, and thus perceived the issue as one of their own future economic interests.


Question:
Did Southern Slavery undercut Poor Whites?

Yes, slavery did undercut poor whites.  This was evident in the South,  economically, socially, and politically. This dynamic played a significant role in slavery's eventual demise, especially as the country exapanded westward.
The majority of whites were laborers, and slavery where it was permitted, limited their opportunities for work, suppressed wages, and concentrated wealth and political power in the hands of a small elite class who owned most of the land and slaves. This system prevented poor whites from acquiring land and achieving upward mobility. The majority of the Southern population did not own slaves and had little hope of competing with wealthy planters who dominated Southern politics, society, and economics.
The Kansas Nebraska act 1854 allowed popular sovereignty to decide whether a new state entering the union would be free or slave state for the first time.  Prior to this, states had been accepted into the union in pairs, one free, one slave in order to maintain an equilibrium in the Senate.  In this way the institution of slavery had been protected by it's protective balance in the U.S. Senate.
As the United States expanded westward, many settlers—who were primarily poor whites or European immigrants—were staunchly opposed to the spread of slavery. They saw it not only as a moral issue but as a direct economic threat. These settlers wanted opportunities to work and build lives for themselves, but in slave-holding areas, enslaved labor would monopolize many of these opportunities.
The South's failure to convince these groups to support the expansion of slavery was a critical turning point. When Kansas entered the Union as a free state, despite violent conflicts like "Bleeding Kansas" between pro-slavery and anti-slavery settlers, it signaled that the South was losing its ability to maintain a balance of power.
The Southern states' decision to secede from the Union, starting with South Carolina in December 1860, was directly tied to their fear of losing this political control. The approval of Kansas as a free state by the U.S. Senate after nearly a decade of obfuscation, in January 1861, solidified their concern that the balance of power had shifted irreversibly against them. They saw the writing on the wall: slavery, as an institution, was being gradually pushed out, and with it, the entire social and economic system of the South would collapse.

This is all very plausible, but 1) no sources given and 2) why in this case did do many ordinary men, including non-slaveholders, risk their lives to defend slavery?

I acknowledge you've cited several events that support your case, but a link explaining e.g. what the Kansas Nebraska act is would be very helpful. I know what it is, but don't assume everyone is familiar with basic facts about the history of your country.

Upvoted, but please cite some sources indicating that the opposition of poor Whites, due to economic concerns, was the cause of supporting its entry as a free state.
